When I type in winecfg it doesn't work
When I type in winecfg in command it doesn't work, and I get this mess.
danielle-zana@danielle-zana-MS-7D17:~$ winecfg
0094:err:winediag:is_broken_driver Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
wine: could not load kernel32.dll, status c0000135
0034:err:winediag:is_broken_driver Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.

I don’t think I changed the NVIDIA driver because it is a fresh install of Ubuntu studio. It still says: using Nidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535(propriety, tested) in software sources on additional drivers tab. It seems to be wine that has broke
I am newish to Linux, so when I got error I don’t understand it and looks like a mess to me. It was working before now it is no longer working, so I don’t know what happened, so how do I fix it please?

Have you done what it said and changed the driver? BTW I do not see a mess I see an error message.

I don’t think i changed driver because it is a fresh install of Ubuntu studio , sorry , I am newish to Linux , so when I got error I don’t understand it and looks like a mess to me. It was working before now it is no longer working , so I don’t know what happened , so how do I fix it please

Hi. Please don't add comments as an answer. Include all relevant information in your question. Thanks.

I am sorry I don’t understand what you mean and what this has to do with my question, sorry I do have autism diagnosis so I don’t know why I am doing wrong, would I have to reformat my machine ? I find the layout of this askunubtu confusing too

It also say I need 50 reputation to comment sometimes and makes the help experience difficult to use , I also haven’t changed my drivers still on Using nvidia-driver-535(propiertary, tested) in software sources , it’s wine thats gone wrong or broke.

I can’t comment on the one above as it says I need 50 reputation, how frustrating

I agree it can be frustrating when you can't comment - but you can always edit information into your question. I'm editing the info into your question, so you can see it as an example.

Thanks , good to know because out of frustration I posted another answer communication sometimes is a challenge in its own and forum limits just make it worse , ok I go bed now and sleep and see how people responded , thank you for your help ❤️

I'm sure everyone will do what they can to help. I don't know much about Wine, but I can help format and edit your question.

Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Sorry the format is tricky... Actually, you are allowed to comment on your own posts and answers to your own posts regardless of reputation - the reason you are not able to do that is that you are logged in on another account - it seems you have created two accounts. You can get this fixed - instructions in this link. In the meantime, if you can log into the account that you used to post the question you will be able to post comments here. Sorry for the inconvenience!

I have found a solution myself, in enabled view hidden files in dolphin file manager. I renamed home/username/.wine to home/username/.bakwine and then ran the command winecfg and it created a new .wine folder with fresh user settings
